# How does block based write reduce overhead?

Tags: c, database, io, storage

I was reading the Wikipedia article on
"Block(data storage)" 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)

The article says

"Blocking reduces the overhead and speeds up the handling of the data-stream."

How does blocking reduce the overhead?

Supposed I have an array of characters

```
long block_size = ...;
char *buf = ...;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "myfile");
```

and loop over this function

```
While(everything in buf not written)
    fwrite(buf, 1, block_size, fp);
    fflush(fp);
```

How does something like this reduce overhead? It seems like this might even increase overhead?
Is the example I gave a correct way of using blocking?

Comment: Your code is not an example of data storage blocking.  Blocking has to do with how data is organized on the storage medium.

Comment: Compared to **what**? And which type of overhead? Execution time? Code? Data? CPU load? ...?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the article, I though it was referring to I/O blocking and that the act of flushing to disk or secondary storage is supposed to be more optimal and take less time.
Can someone clarify the wikipedia page?

Comment: This is actually a pretty good question.  These days many developers don't think much about the underlying storage mechanics (which is just fine most of the time). Sometimes it matters, and it's good to understand such fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you want to write data.  The number of bytes you want to write is `N*block_size+C`, where N and C are just non-negative constants.

If you modify your code to

```
While(everything in buf not written)
    fwrite(buf, 1, not_a_multiple_of_the_block_size, fp);
    fflush(fp);
```

You force additional IO operations.  Let's say for example that

not_a_multiple_of_the_block_size = 1.5 * block_size

The first iteration of your loop will write a whole block as well as half a block of data.  Physically, the IO subsystem must retrieve two blocks, filling one entirely and one half-way with your data.

The next iteration will require the block where the first half-block was written to be retrieved from storage, updated, and written back to storage plus one new block.

For the first two iterations of the loop, you have one additional fetch operation to bring the contents of the second block into memory<sup>1</sup>, compared to if you had used block-sized writes (or an integer multiple of the block size).  If you are using a rotating hard disk (or a tape drive), you have to wait until that block is physically positioned under the read head.

Modern hardware tends to minimize the additional overhead through caching (note that the Wikipedia article mentions tape drives by name...) but there will in general still be some additional overhead when not using an integer multiple of the block size.

<sup>1</sup>*The data may well be brought into memory on the IO subsystem controller, not necessarily into system RAM.*

Comment: So ideally I should be writing in multiple of  512bytes? (If this was written on hard drive). Considering that each block of the hard drive is 512?
Would fwrite not automatically do this?

Comment: If you call fwrite with a buffer size of 513 bytes, it will write 512 bytes to one block plus one byte to a different block.  Next time through it will load the block with one byte, write 511 additional bytes to that block, and the additional 2 bytes to the next block.  And so on.  If you call it with a buffer size of 5120+1, it will make an efficient write to 10 blocks, filling them with 512 bytes each, and then write 1 byte to an 11th block.